# From a date range count all dates in column 1 that exists in column 2 in excel

Tags: excel

Lets say I have a date range like so

- A2 = 2/1/17
- B2 = 2/15/17

In Row H I have a few dates.  Will call this range RDO

- H2 = 2/6/2017
- H3 = 2/13/2017
- H4 = 2/20/2017
- H5 = 2/27/2017

In Row I I have other dates.  Will call this range Holidays

- I2 = 1/16/2017
- I3 = 2/13/2017
- I4 = 2/20/2017

Now in row C2, I have the following formula

- =NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)

In D2, I have the following formula

- =NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)

In E2, I have the following formula

- =$C2-NETWORKDAYS($A2,$B2,I2:I5)

What formula can I write in F2 that will give me all dates within range A2:B2 That are both in column H and I?  In this example 2/13/2017 exists within the range 2/1/2017 and 2/15/2017 in both columns H AND I.  The answer should be 1

Comment: You need a unique list of dates from **columns** H:I. That's difficult with native worksheet formulas but a VBA UDF could perform this handily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to add a column J, then:

```
// copy this down
J2: =IF(COUNTIF(I:I,H2)>0,H2,"")

F2: =COUNTIF(J2:J5,">"&A2)-COUNTIF(J2:J5,"<"&B2)
```